# Only first element in MySQL IN statement is searched

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have some query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `subjects` WHERE `teacher_id` IN ( 7, 11, 32 )
```

if teacher_id have this values:

```
teacher_id = 7, 5, 9
```

you will get result of that field, but if teacher_id have this values:

```
teacher_id = 5, 11, 9
```

it wont find any result.

So, this query works only for first element.

Comment: How can teacher_id have 3 values? Can you please post your tables with sample data?

Comment: @mosty: badly designed table and it's a string field. it needs to be normalized

Comment: For every subject 3,4 professors have privilege to do something. In this array ( I put it like type VARCHAR ) are ids of those professors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So? That's to be expected. The following two statements are functionally identical:

```
WHERE x IN (1,2,3)
WHERE (x = 1) OR (x = 2) OR (x = 3)
```

When your DB field contains the literal text `1,2`, then the comparison will be:

```
WHERE x = '1,2'
```

and be treated as a string comparison. Since you've doing `int = string`, the string is converted to int, which means the `,2` is stripped off, and you end up with

```
WHERE x = 1
```

You should fix your table structure and normalize that field. There are VERY few usage cases where putting multiple-values fall into a table, and you are NOT in one of those cases.